# Tooltip for grid column name in Kendo UI Angular 2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

How can I show a tooltip for the Kendo UI Angular 2 grid column name?
I've tried using the html *title* attribute, but it conflicts with *kendo-grid-column* title property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert a span with a title in the template:

```
<template kendoHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
  <span title={{column.field}}>{{column.field}}({{columnIndex}})</span>
</template>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/eYtBLMv45XFLcnbXn2ZW?p=preview

Comment: @knikolov, Thanks for that. It only worked for me in grid only when I used **kendoGridHeaderTemplate**, instead of just **kendoHeaderTemplate**... So my updated code is 

`<template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
  <span title={{column.field}}>{{column.field}}({{columnIndex}})</span>
</template>`